# Scala pattern matching with tuple: matching equal values in the tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have created a function to retrieve a given value from the Pascal Triangle and I've used `if` statements. Now I want to refactor the function to use pattern matching.

My `if` based function looks like this:

```
def valueAt(row: Int, column: Int): Int = {
  // ...
  else if (row == column) 1 // last column
  // 
}
```

My second version of this function, using pattern matching has the following signature:

```
def valueAt2(row: Int, column: Int): Int = (row, column) match {
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to define a `case` for when the `row` and `column` have the same value?

I have tried using the same variable name in the `case`, like this:

```
case (x, x) => 1 // last column
```

And I have also tried to use the value of the `row` in the column, like this:

```
case (_, row) => 1 // last column
```

But they don't work. In the first case I have a compilation error and in the second the IDE says that I'm shadowing the variable `row` from the `match`.

It this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, use an if guard:

```
(1, 2) match { case (x, y) if x == y => 1; ... }
```

For the second one, when you want to match a variable (instead of binding and shadowing it), you can use backticks (`):

```
(1, 2) match { case (_, `row`) => 1; ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **guard**, which is a part of a case expression that can check non-stable conditions, and not surprisingly resembles an `if` statement:

```
 (row, column) match {
    case (x, y) if x == y => 1
    // other cases...
 }
```

Note that inputs not matching this guard (i.e. for which `x != y`) would continue to check the other cases, so, for example, another case `case (x, y) => ...` can follow, and assume `x != y`.